# How to set entity rotation using document.querySelector or other script techniques?

Tags: rotation, aframe

I'm trying to set up a simple a-frame physics demonstration that replays on click. Following basic examples from the aframe physics system and the orange shooter demo, I've simplified things to the code bellow which seems to work fine except for  the rotation.set action.  The block resets position, velocity and angularVelocity just fine but does not update rotation as it seems it should.  Browser console message is *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined*

What would be the simplest way to set the rotation from within this script?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-system@1.4.0/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene physics background="color: #ccddff">
      <a-box id="dropped" position="-1 4 -3" rotation="40 45 0" color="#5577D9" dynamic-body></a-box>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="brown" static-body></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
   <script>
    window.addEventListener('click', function () {
       // METHOD2 - MOVE THE EXISTING ORANGE
      document.querySelector("#dropped").body.position.set(-1, 4, -3);
      document.querySelector("#dropped").body.velocity.set(0, 0, 0);
      document.querySelector("#dropped").body.angularVelocity.set(0, 0, 0);
      document.querySelector("#dropped").body.rotation.set(40, 45, 0);
    });    
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `document.querySelector("#dropped").components.body.body.position.set(-1, 4, -3);`

Comment: Position, velocity and angular velocity updates already work in the original submission.  The  *document.querySelector("#dropped").components.body.body.position.set(-1, 4, -3);* statement does not work for position, nor could I get variations of it to work for rotation.   There seems to be something different about updating the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 document.querySelector("#dropped").body.quaternion.set(0.3535533905932738,0.3535533905932738,0.14644660940672624,0.8535533905932737);
```

Apparently you have to use quaternions for rotations while physics is added, it looks like it overrides the native rotation. This works for getting one from degrees (45,45,0):

```
q=new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(THREE.Math.degToRad(45),THREE.Math.degToRad(45),0,'XYZ'));
```

And then:

```
document.querySelector("#dropped").body.quaternion.set(q.x,q.y,q.z,q.w);
```

But **neither** of this worked for me:

```
document.querySelector("#dropped").body.quaternion=q
document.querySelector("#dropped").body.quaternion.setFromEuler(e)
```

Where **e** is an Euler and **q** is a quaternion. Also the following works, albeit the result is not quite what you need:

```
document.querySelector("#dropped").body.quaternion=document.querySelector("#dropped").body.initQuaternion;
```

Should probably ask about it on A-frame github. Hope that this helps, happy coding ))